# Interpolation of spectra: uneven sampling to even sampling

Tags: fitting, interpolation, spectral-analysis, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have a spectrum. Specifically, my data is relative intensity $[I_{\tilde{\nu}}]$ versus wavenumbers $[\tilde{\nu}]$. The wavenumbers are equally sampled so that ${d\tilde{\nu}} = c$, where $c$ is some constant.

However, I need the data to be given in terms of wavelength $\lambda = \frac{1}{\tilde{\nu}}$.
When I perform this transformation, the step size of wavelength $d \lambda$ decreases with increasing wavelength. However, I need the step size to remain constant for the entire spectrum.

I am guessing this calls for some kind of interpolation or fitting. How can an even sampling of wavelengths $\lambda$ be accomplished?

Comment: See for instance:  https://www.marum.de/Binaries/Binary2506/spectrum.pdf

Comment: I guess [this is the reference](https://bayes.wustl.edu/glb/book.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a cubic spline interpolation of the spectrum on an evenly sampled wavelength grid.